# How do you localize the field names in ActiveModel error messages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, localization, activemodel

```
# in the login form in new.html.haml
= f.label :email, t('.email')

# in fi.yml
fi:
  activemodel:
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email: 
              taken: "on jo käytössä." # means "is in use"

# The actual error message generated
=>"Email on jo käytössä."
```

So it adds the field name before the rest of the error message.. but the field name isn't translated..

Can I add a translation for label email, and if yes, where should it go so that ActiveModel finds it?
If not, what is the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, like so

```
fi:
  activemodel:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "Sähköposti"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              taken: "on jo käytössä."
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem

> ```
> fi:
>   activemodel:
>     attributes:
>       user:
>         email: "Sähköposti"
> ```

Your example did not work for me, but sent me on the right track.
I changed activemodel: for activerecord: which worked in my case.

I also realized I could change

```
f.label :email, t('.email')
```

to

```
f.label :email
```

and still keep my translation.

Have not tried it with haml. I used erb in my case. Don't know if that has anything to say.

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 3.2, you have to change `activemodel` key for `activerecord`:

```
fi:
  activerecord:
    attributes:
      user:
        email: "Sähköposti"
    errors:
      models:
        user:
          attributes:
            email:
              taken: "on jo käytössä."
```

Also, take in consideration that if the model is inside a module you have to indicate it:

```
    attributes:
      a_module/user:
```

Here it is the [link to the official Rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models).

Answer (score 1):

The following works for me to translate the f.label in the _form of my model.

In the config/locales/yourlanguage.yml file :

```
fr:
  helpers:
    label:
      mymodel:
        attribute1: 'translation1'
        attribute2: 'translation2'
```